# Best way to track in a database whether a script successfully completes

Tags: php, mysql, tracking

I'm using PHP/MySQL, although I think this question is essentially language/db ambivalent. I have a PHP script that connects to one API, gets the response data, parses it, and then sends it to a different API for storage in its database. Sometimes this process fails because of an error with one of the APIs. I would therefore like to easily track its success/failure.

I should clarify that "success" in this case is defined as the script getting the data it needs from the first API and successfully having it processed by the second API. Therefore, "failure" could result from 3 possible things:

1. First API throws an error
2. Second API throws an error
3. My script times out.

This script will run once a day. I'd like to store the success or failure result in a database so that I can easily visit a webpage and see the result. I'm currently thinking of doing the following:

1. Store the current time in a variable at the start of the script.
2. Insert that timestamp into the database right away.
3. Once the script has finished, insert that same timestamp into the database
   again.
4. If the script fails, log the reason for failure in the DB.

I'd then gauge success or failure based on whether a single timestamp has two entries in the database, as opposed to just one.

Is this the best way to do it, or would something else work better? I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work, but I feel like some recognized standard way of accomplishing this must exist.

Comment: It seems like you have a method that would work, try it out.

Comment: Just added the last paragraph on. I'm not worried that my method won't work. However, the need I describe seems like something that must be very commonplace, and therefore I'm wondering if there is some recognized standard approach.

Comment: How about just a simple "time job started" record, and record the time the job ended? Jobs with no end times failed. Then you'd also be recording how long the operation required to complete.

Comment: @MarcB - in that case, I'd need to generate a unique job ID since I can no longer use the timestamp as the unique identifier of an individual job. But that's fine, and I like the added advantage of recording how long the job took. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A user declared shutdown function might be an alternative: using [register_shutdown_function()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) you can decalre a callback to be executed when the script terminates, whethe rsuccessfully, user-aborted, or timed-out

Comment: There are times when my script can fail without terminating because of a time-out (i.e. one of the APIs I mentioned throws an error). In such a case, I assume this function you provided would not actually get called. Therefore, I still need a way to record whether the script was successful or not beyond just testing whether it timed out. However, there may be times when it DOES fail because of timing out, and this function will let me note that in my database. So thanks!

Comment: I've not actually tried register_shutdown_function to see whether it executes in the event of an error (other than timeout) but it's easy enough to test

Comment: That's ok -- I think I'd prefer to catch the error thrown by one of the APIs rather than have an error actually occur in my script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lock file :

- at the very beginning of your script, you create a lock file somewhere on the filesystem
- at the very end of your script, if everything worked good, you delete it from filesystem

Then you've just to monitor the directory where you've placed these files. With the lock file's creation date you can find which day didn't work.

You can combine this system by a monitoring script that sends alerts if lock files are present and have a creation date older than a given interval (let's say 1 hour for example if your script usually runs in a few minutes).

Comment: Are there any advantages to this over the approach I described?

Comment: I would say yes because the chance to have a db connection problem is more important than an empty file creation error.